# How to render one panel and stop rendering another panel using selectOneMenu in jsf

Tags: jsf, richfaces, selectonemenu

I Have following code:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{UserAccessHandler.isAitfCompany}">
    <!-- For the dropdown sensorlist -->
    <h:outputLabel value="#{labelBundle.device}"
        style="font-weight:bold; padding-right:15px;" />
    <h:selectOneMenu id="testing"
        value="#{SystemHealthPageModel.selectedSensorId}"
        styleClass="facility_dropDown_list">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="----" /> 
        <f:selectItems
            value="#{SystemHealthPageModel.childFacilitySelectionList}" />
        <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" execute="@this"
            render="systemHealthAlert" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>


</h:panelGroup>

<rich:panel id="allSystemHealthAlert">
<alert:system_health_alert alertList="#{SystemHealthPageModel.allSystemAlerts}"
                numberOfRows="#{SystemHealthPageModel.numberOfAlertsToDisplayOnOnePage}"
                displayAssetRelatedData="true"
                moreThanOnePageOfResults="#{SystemHealthPageModel.showMoreThan1PageOfAlerts}"/>
</rich:panel>

<rich:panel id="systemHealthAlert">
<alert:system_health_alert alertList="#{SystemHealthPageModel.systemAlerts}"
                numberOfRows="#{SystemHealthPageModel.numberOfAlertsToDisplayOnOnePage}"
                displayAssetRelatedData="true"
                moreThanOnePageOfResults="#{SystemHealthPageModel.showMoreThan1PageOfAlerts}"/>
</rich:panel>
```

Actually I have two panels. When I will render "systemHealthAlert" panel using selectOneMenu at that time I want to stop render other panel named as "allsystemHealthAlert". For you information "allsystemHealthAlert" is automatically loaded during initial page load. I dont want to render this panel when I will render "systemHealthAlert" panel using selectOneMenu. Is there any way to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Please give the full code so its easy to understand.

Comment: Code edited. Full code is there. @Bhola.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your panels in a wider container and point it from your `<h:selectOneMenu />` instead. Then, perform a conditional rendering of `<rich:panel />` elements depending on `#{SystemHealthPageModel.selectedSensorId}` value.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="testing"
    value="#{SystemHealthPageModel.selectedSensorId}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="----" /> 
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{SystemHealthPageModel.childFacilitySelectionList}" />
    <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" execute="@this"
        render="grouperPanel" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:panelGroup id="grouperPanel">
    <rich:panel id="allSystemHealthAlert" rendered="#{empty SystemHealthPageModel.selectedSensorId}">
        <alert:system_health_alert alertList="#{SystemHealthPageModel.allSystemAlerts}"
            numberOfRows="#{SystemHealthPageModel.numberOfAlertsToDisplayOnOnePage}"
            displayAssetRelatedData="true"
            moreThanOnePageOfResults="#{SystemHealthPageModel.showMoreThan1PageOfAlerts}"/>
    </rich:panel>

    <rich:panel id="systemHealthAlert" rendered="#{not empty SystemHealthPageModel.selectedSensorId}">
        <alert:system_health_alert alertList="#{SystemHealthPageModel.systemAlerts}"
            numberOfRows="#{SystemHealthPageModel.numberOfAlertsToDisplayOnOnePage}"
            displayAssetRelatedData="true"
            moreThanOnePageOfResults="#{SystemHealthPageModel.showMoreThan1PageOfAlerts}"/>
    </rich:panel> 
</h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

We will achieve this using a listener method then rerendering the components.

**(1) Code**

Your xhtml page :

```
<h:panelGroup id="panels">
    <rich:panel rendered="#{managedBean.showAllSystem}">
        <h:outputText value="ONEONE" />
    </rich:panel>
    <rich:panel rendered="#{not managedBean.showAllSystem}">
        <h:outputText value="TWOTWO" />
    </rich:panel>
</h:panelGroup>
```

And

```
<a4j:ajax listener="#{managedBean.menuValueChanged}" render="panels" />
```

Your managed bean :

```
int selectedSensorId;
boolean showAllSystem;

// getters and setters

public void menuValueChanged() {
    // business logic    
    // for example
    if(selectedSensorId == 0) {
        showAllSystem = true;
    } else {
        showAllSystem = false;
    }
}
```

**(2) Workflow**

1- First, in order to update a component using AJAX, you should be able to call it by its client id. in case the component is sometimes not rendered, it will be getting a generated client id that you won't be knowing beforehand. One solution is to encapsulate the to-be-rendered components with an always rendered component (Better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11835864/696299))

2- in your managed bean you will create a toggle flag, let's call it `showAllSystem`, if it is `true` it will show `allSystemHealthAlert` and hide `systemHealthAlert`. this flag will be used by the panels' `rendered` attributes.

3- you will then create the listener method, let's call it `menuValueChanged()` that will set the `showAllSystem` flag depending on the `selectedSensorId` and will be called by the listener in your `a4j:ajax` tag

Comment: 1) Your listener definition is missing the `()`, they're not optional with your method definition. 2) You need to re-render a id that exists on the page (see @XtremeBiker's approach), or JSF won't find the target to re-render when the response comes back.

Comment: number (1) is totally incorrect, in EL we can call a method without parentheses if we're not passing parameters to it http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-el003.htm#BNAHZ and i will punish myself for number (2) by writing 100 times : `encapsulate the to-be-rendered-using-ajax component with an ALWAYS rendered component` .. i'll edit my answer. Cheers !

Comment: Have you tried (1)? If it works, tell me. What I understood is that leaving the parens off is only allowed if the expected method signature takes no parameters. The `listener` methods [take](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) an `AjaxBehaviorEvent`.

Comment: Yes, and it works. Actually when you don't specify an event, it takes the `UIComponent`'s default event (e.g. onchange for inputText and valuechange for selectOneMenu)